# Converting a list into comma separated and add quotes in python

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have :

```
val = '[12 13 14 16 17 18]'
```

I want to have:

```
['12','13','14','16','17','18']
```

I have done

```
x = val.split(' ')
y = (" , ").join(x)
```

The result is

```
'[12 , 13 , 14 , 16 , 17 , 18 ]'
```

But not the exact one also the quotes

What's the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: Using regular expressions: `re.findall(r'\d+', val)`

Comment: `val.strip('[]').split()` But I would question how you got that original input

Comment: `val = val[1:-1].split()`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list ?

Comment: How is this related to Pandas?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with

```
val.strip('[]').split()
```

Answer (score 1):

Only if you can handle a `regex`:

```
import re

val = '[12 13 14 16 17 18]'
print(re.findall(r'\d+', val))

# ['12', '13', '14', '16', '17', '18']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> val
'[12 13 14 16 17 18]'
>>> val.strip("[]").split(" ")
['12', '13', '14', '16', '17', '18']
```

Comment: can just `strip('[]')` once

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
val = '[12 13 14 16 17 18]'
val = val[1:-1].split()
print(val)
```

Output:

```
['12', '13', '14', '16', '17', '18']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you realy need the paranthesis

```
val = '[12 13 14 16 17 18]'
val = val.replace('[','')
val = val.replace(']','')
val = val.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` after replacing whitespace with comma:

```
from ast import literal_eval

val = '[12 13 14 16 17 18]'
res = list(map(str, literal_eval(val.replace(' ', ','))))

print(res, type(res))

['12', '13', '14', '16', '17', '18'] <class 'list'>
```

Comment: I believe the wants a list of strings